# <textarea> with horizontal rule

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of a way to create horizontal rules within a `<textarea>` without using a background image?

CSS3 would be fine. I can bodge an image fallback for IE if necessary.

Example:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727669/textarea-with-underline-component-whole-width-text

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do this using linear gradients:

```css
.notes {
    background-attachment: local;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    line-height: 31px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="notes"></textarea>
```

[JSFiddle Version](https://jsfiddle.net/nr5L8z0d/)

Comment: And we have a winner! Thanks minitech. That never even crossed my mind.

Comment: @3rror404: Also, edited to add the padding from your image. Phew! That's a lot of gradients...

Comment: I'm impressed! Thanks for taking the time to work it out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Good solution. It does suffer slightly when you have many lines and you get the need for scrolling (in FF at least). Not sure how solvable this is nicely...

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I've noticed that Firefox has problems rendering gradients like that - perhaps `-moz-repeating-gradient` would work better?

Comment: Is there any option to control the height\position of the lines?

Comment: @undroid: `background-position` will alter their position, and to change the size, you’d have to change all the 30px and 31px to whichever size you wanted and that plus 1px.

Comment: Is it possible to get "dashed" lines somehow though?

Comment: @carestad: Yep, if you have a fixed background colour, you can put another repeating gradient that goes on a layer above the lines from left to right and erases the spaces between the dashes: transparent background transparent background …. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @carestad: (That’s also how the existing left and right sides work – the grey lines go across the entire width, then there are two white gradients on either side to cover them.)

Comment: @Ry- Alright. I understand the concept, but I struggle with the whole linear-gradient syntax though. You wouldn't by any chance be able to provide a pen/fiddle with a "dashed" solution, would you?

Answer (score 16):

```css
.notes {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 31px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    line-height: 31px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
}

.notes:focus {
    outline: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: No! Please read the question again. Your solution - [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cuuoz5o4re7z4sw/Screenshot%202015-03-01%2014.51.12.png?dl=0), but I want - [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/km8pwik21nc4zr9/Screenshot%202015-02-23%2003.15.37.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be a background image. Look up on CSS background or background-image property then assign it the textarea in question.

Comment: No. If I'll scroll this textarea, text will look like [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3bhxa21daodz5x/Screenshot%202015-02-23%2003.26.14.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

I think using an image is the right solution.

Fallback: transparent background on the textarea, background-image on a wrapper DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, it's not possible to format text inside a textarea.

If this is really important I'd suggest using `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` which allows you to style the text (but it's open to potential abuse from pasted HTML), and then parse our innerHTML to a hidden input field upon submitting your form.

Answer (score 0):

**Universal solution**

1. Create two divs with the same styling.
2. First div is a "mirror" div with `color: transparent; position: absolute`.
3. Second div is `contenteditable="true"`, with injected `span` elements.
4. Add any `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom`

[Live Demo](https://0x8y7.csb.app/)

[CodeSandbox editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-component-with-line-bottom-borders-0x8y7?file=/src/App.vue) (using Vue, but easy to port to anything else)

Note: Please be careful with contenteditable and make sure you secured it from XSS attacks.