# Textarea with horizontal rule showing up on print

Tags: html, css, printing, textarea

I am currently working on a website where a user can look at a mechanical request by a customer on the site. They can then print the request.

I am trying to add a "notes" section to the request only on the printed version. I am using bootstrap, so hiding it until print is easy.

My problem is that I want to have horizontal lines in the textarea, exactly like this answer: [<textarea> with horizontal rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468153/textarea-with-horizontal-rule/9468502)

The lines work great on the the textarea. The problem is that they do not show up when calling window.print()

On the page:

[image]

When printing:

[image]

Is there a way to make this show up on the print version?

```
<dt class="visible-print">
    Notes
</dt>

<dd class="visible-print">
    <textarea class="notes" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
</dd>
```

```
.notes {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 31px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    line-height: 31px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most folks have their browsers set to the default option "do not print backgrounds." A dark-background page can eat up your ink fast! 
If your "lines" are implemented leveraging "background," they won't print.

As a workaround, try creating an independent image. Set its z-index appropriately (remember to use position), and then hide it from the screen css, showing it only for the print css.

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of that. I'm a beginner in html and css, please add an example

Comment: Can you be more specific about what has you stumped? Stacking things with z-index? Or creating separate print / screen css files? Something else?

Comment: You do realise that this question is more than 4 months old right? If I hadn't managed to make it work by now, obviously the deadline was a long time ago. I didn't manage to do anything you said except creating an image manually with the lines I needed, and then putting it in there with a css hiding it when not printing. That's why I marked it as accepted, since the idea actually worked, even though that wasn't your main point (which I didn't understand)

Comment: My apologies; I did not see your comment then. Sorry for leaving you in the lurch.

Comment: @KaitoKid, you should delete comments asking for help if they are no longer relevant. Just because you got it to work, or the deadline passed, doesn't mean you wouldn't still be interested in improving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported in similar situations with how the `<textarea>` gets rendered before printing. A solution worth looking at is to duplicate the `<textarea>` as a standard `<div>` or other element before/when calling for printing.

A resource showing an example of how to go about replacing a `<textarea>` using jQuery can be found here: http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2011/02/07/how-to-replace-textarea-tags-with-simple-div-tag-including-it-content-for-a-printing-view/.