# Textarea with horizontal rule, inconsistent number of lines

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have a similar situation as the poster in the question [Textarea with horizontal rule showing up on print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115762/textarea-with-horizontal-rule-showing-up-on-print), and I used the same code, but use variables to allow easy adjustment of heights and colors. The problem is that when I go to print from Chrome, some textareas have 3 lines, some have 2; yet I can confirm that each element has the same height. Also, sometimes the first line is much lighter than the rest of them. I attached an image of the print-out [generated from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPRO5.png).

Why is Chrome not respecting the height of the element? What can I do to keep it stable? Why is Chrome changing the color?

```
@hrule-height: 40px;
@hrule-color: #aaa;
@hrule-background-color: white;

.item-response-lg {
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(@hrule-background-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color (@hrule-height + 1), @hrule-background-color (@hrule-height + 1));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(to left, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(@hrule-background-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color (@hrule-height + 1), @hrule-background-color (@hrule-height + 1));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(to left, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(@hrule-background-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color (@hrule-height + 1), @hrule-background-color (@hrule-height + 1));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(to left, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(@hrule-background-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color (@hrule-height + 1), @hrule-background-color (@hrule-height + 1));
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(to left, @hrule-background-color 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(@hrule-background-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color @hrule-height, @hrule-color (@hrule-height + 1), @hrule-background-color (@hrule-height + 1));
        background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% (@hrule-height + 1);
        border: none;
        line-height: (@hrule-height + 1);
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        height: (@hrule-height * 2-2);
}
```

Checking that each has the same height.. both return a value of 82 for each.

```
$$('textarea').forEach((e) => console.log(e.clientHeight))
$$('textarea').forEach((e) => console.log(e.scrollHeight))
```

Comment: I feel like both problems might have something to do with the first "line" of the gradient being the first pixel or two of the element's background. The code gets a little complicated for me to think clearly, but maybe if I can offset the gradient so that it starts 5px in rather than at 0/1, that would do it?

Comment: I didn't take a good shot of the result, but the first line you see (the faint one) is the first line of a textarea's background gradient. Compare it to the next textarea, which has only 2 lines; yet both have the same height and everything looks fine when rendered on the screen. The problem is the rendering for print media.