# Printing lines in textarea doesn't work consistently

Tags: javascript, css, printing, textarea

I've been trying to use this code to print lines in my textarea:

[<textarea> with horizontal rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468153/textarea-with-horizontal-rule)

This is the code:

```css
.notes {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-size: 100% 31px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    line-height: 31px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
}

.notes:focus {
    outline: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="notes"></textarea>
```

I use multiple textarea boxes in my table with multiple TD cells. My textarea boxes also resize in height from 21px, 42px and 63px when I use another function, but the font and lines in the textarea remain the same.  Everything looks fine on screen.

The problem is when I try to print it, the lines in my textarea boxes will not show up sometimes.

I use a code to print my webpage content filled with inputs, textarea using the following code:

> frameDoc.document.write('.worksheet_format_part2_input_textbox
>   {background-color:white; background-image:
>   -webkit-linear-gradient(white,white 18px, #ccc 18px, #ccc 20px, white 20px); background-size: 100% 20px; line-height: 20px; font-size:13px;
>   padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }');

For example, if I set my textarea height to 63px it shows 4 input lines and 3 print lines.  However some cells will only have 2 print lines (1st input line is bigger than the 2nd and 3rd, no 4th input line).

What could be the issue here?

Update: Ok I'm not sure if I've explained it properly but basically I'm trying to add lines to my textarea and resizing them using javascript, which later gets printed.  On screen it all appears as they should be but as soon as I preview it for printing the textarea lines are missing.

I looked into the code that resizes my textarea and it appears that this is what causes the problem when I change the height, for example:

> var e_notes=document.getElementsByClassName('notes'); for(var i = 0; i
>   < e_notes.length; i++) {
>                   e_notes[i].style.height= "90px"; 
>   //                e_notes[i].style.height= 4 + "em";
>               }

'notes' is the name of the textarea class that all my textarea elements are using.  In the CSS I've set a fixed width and height (height:100px;width:100px;).  Setting the new height to 90px will work, but then the lines will go missing. If I set it to 100px (original size) then the lines show up.  I'm still working on it.  It seems that may need to reload the textarea elements again?

Comment: *"My textarea boxes also resize in height from 21px, 42px and 63px when I use another function"* - Your demo textbox also resizes in height *and* width if the user drags the bottom-right corner. And if the user enters more text than fits the text can be scrolled in a way that the lines go through the words.

Comment: Resizing is not a problem.  The end result is what appears in print, which doesn't show all of the lines in some textarea boxes (which are all the same size).

Comment: I found out that changing the height of the textarea in javascript creates the problem (e_notes[i].style.height= "200px";), but if I use the original height of my textarea (100px) and set it to that (ie. e_notes[i].style.height= "100px";) then it will show the lines properly. But that takes me back to the beginning. I want to be able to resize it to 200px.