# How to draw separator between lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, css, textarea

Is it possible to draw a separator between lines in **textarea** using only CSS, like in the picture below:

[image]

Note: I know this is very easy if I used table by creating a new row using javascript for each element, but I'm exploring if there is a simple solution using only CSS for textarea

Thank you,

Comment: You can set a background image for that textarea with lines in the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468153/textarea-with-horizontal-rule

Comment: @RachelGallen you got exactly the same of what I want, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve it by css linear gradient. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6yayer2x/)

css

```
 textarea {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  0,
  #222,
  #222 1px,
  #333 1px,
  #333 20px
);
 color: #fff; 
}
```

html

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think it is very nice solution, although I was thinking more of a dynamically adding a separator when I start typing, I don't know if that is possible with textarea 
(it has to be possible but how easy it is)