# Textarea with underline (component whole width) text

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components, textarea, underline

**I need a textarea as follows :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear gradients:

```css
textarea{
        background-attachment: local;
        background-image:
            linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px),
            linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px),
            repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
        line-height: 31px;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        width: 500px;
        }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: **@Dream Bold**,  increasing font size and other styling make underline position wrongly.

Comment: Did you increase the font size for the textarea?

Comment: `repeating-linear-gradient( white, white 35px, #ccc 35px, #ccc 36px, white 36px )`

Change these values according to the lineheight

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/OJZwgBm?editors=1100